# Find and redirect to capture pattern filename

Tags: awk, find

I'm looking a way to do something like:

```
find /path -name "201[2-6]*" | awk -F"/" '{print $5"/"$6"/"$7"/"$8",0,0,0"}' > archives_201\1.csv
```

where `archives_201\1.csv` could be `archives_201[2-6].csv` the result of capture of filename.

I know that i could do by looping over the year. Because the folder may contains ~ 100 millions file, I should avoid it.

**[EDIT]**

I also tried

```
 find /path -name "201[2-6]" | awk -F"/" 'BEGIN {print $5"/"$6"/"$7"/"$8",0,0,0" > ${8:0:4}"_export_0504.csv"}'
```

but got

```
awk: BEGIN {print $5"/"$6"/"$7"/"$8",0,0,0" > ${8:0:4}"_export_0504.csv"}
awk:                                                                  ^ syntax error
```

Comment: You should describe what you are trying to obtain rather than just posting a command that does ***NOT*** do what you want. Moreover, this is no fun without sample files to try and manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1:**

Process files residing in `/path`, whose name starts with `201`, followed by a single digit between `2` and `6`, followed by any character.

Split up each line on the `/` character, and compose a line with the fields `5`, `6`, `7`, and `8` having a `/` between them, followed by a `",0,0,0"` string.

Store that line, and any subsequent ones, in a file named a file whose name is `archives_201` followed by the same single digit found earlier in the input filename, with extension `.csv`.

**Solution 1:**

```
awk -F/ '
    FNR==1 {match(FILENAME, /\/(201[2-6])/, m)}
    {print $5"/"$6"/"$7"/"$8",0,0,0" >> "archives_"m[1]".csv"}
' /path/201[2-6]*
```

---

**Comments:**

Since you don't provide sample input files and desired output, I had to do some guesswork on multiple points.

I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish with: `> ${8:0:4}"_export_0504.csv"`.

Piping `find` results into `awk` leaves me puzzled: do you want `awk` to actually read each file or just process a text list? If the latter, the rigid composition of fields `($5"/"$6"/"$7"/"$8)` means you expect all files to be in the same directory, so why use `find` at all?

I assumed there is no path part, other than the filename, that begins with the search string `201[2-6]`. I assumed you want to add (`>>`) multiple lines to the same file rather than overwriting it if needed (`>`). I assumed all files are in the same directory and I assumed `awk` is to work on file *contents* rather that on file *names*.

The choice of `/` as field separator hints towards the latter hypothesis, though, so I'll try to solve that problem as well.

---

**Problem 2:**

Process filenames of files residing in `/path`, whose name starts with `201`, followed by a single digit between `2` and `6`, followed by any character.

Split up each filename on the `/` character, and compose a line with the 5th,  6th, 7th, and 8th components (preserving the `/` between them), followed by a `",0,0,0"` string.

Store that line, and any subsequent ones, in a file named `archives_201` followed by the same single digit found earlier in the filename, with extension `.csv`.

**Solution 2:**

```
awk -F/ '
    FNR==1 {
        match(FILENAME, /\/(201[2-6])/, m);
        $0=FILENAME;
        print $5"/"$6"/"$7"/"$8",0,0,0" >> "archives_"m[1]".csv"
    }
' /path/201[2-6]*
```